# Send variable from nodejs into js file that has rendered alongside html

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm pretty new to nodejs.

How do I pass a variable in my app.js, to the app.js file that renders together with my html? Is this possible?

For example, as below, trying to send the value of myvar to the /public/js/app.js file. I am aware that I could set it up as an inline script through the ejs file, just was looking for better alternatives to that.

```
app.js

app.use(express.static("public"));

//

app.get("/my-page", function (req, res) {

    var myvar = "Hello"
 
    res.render("my-page.ejs");
  }
});

//
```

```
/views/my-page.ejs

<h1>Hello World</h1>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/app.js"></script>
```

```
/public/js/app.js

var myvar2 = myvar + " World!"

console.log(myvar2)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Express as a framework you can use "Express.js res.locals Property".

```
app.js
    
app.use(express.static("public"));
    
app.get("/my-page", function (req, res) {
    
  var myvar = "Hello";

  res.locals.myvar = myvar; //You can set up the variable here

  res.render("my-page.ejs");
});
```

And then in the html you can access through:

```
/public/js/app.js

var myvar2 = window.myvar + " World!"; // You can access through window object

console.log(myvar2);
```

Then since you are using EJS template expression you can access it through:

```
<h1><%= myvar %></h1>
```

For more info you can look at [express page](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html)

Some other way to access to the variable from HTML would be:

```
<script>
  var myVarContainer = document.getElementById("myvar");

  myVarContainer.innerHTML = '<%= myvar %>'; // Set the innerHTML with the variable value
</script>
```

But overall If its something more complex I would suggest you to use some library or framework (React or Angular) for data binding.

The app.locals object contains properties that are accessible as local variables within the application and can be used in templates rendered with res.render. For safer lets say way of rendering you can use:

```
app.get("/my-page", function (req, res) {
  var myvar = "Hello";
  res.render("my-page", { myvar: myvar }); // send the variable through render method from res.
});
```

For more information check the official documentation that I've linked previously.

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks! Is there a safer way to load 'myvar' through html? Especially if it has more sensitive content?

Comment: You can use server side render if you want to be more "secure". Something before the js is sent to frontend. I've updated my answer so you can check it out

Answer (score 1):

JSON to the rescue. We send a `<script>` tag with the proper values. The trick is rendering the template file into html first, but express offers a callback for that.

```js
// in node.js:

function my_render(res, template, data, obj) {

  res.render(template, data, function(err, html) {
    if (err) {
      throw new Error("something")
    }

    html += "\n<scr" + "ipt>var my_var = " + JSON.stringify(obj) + ";</scr" + "ipt>";

    res.send(html);
  });

}

// in client:
// my_var = object that was on server
```